# netstat outputs same local adress for 2 different connections

Tags: ip, netstat

Trying to understand how to read netstat output.

In my browser I opened site1.com

On my server **netstat -A inet -p -e** outputs the following:

```
tcp        0      0 site1.com:www     foreign-adress:37991 ESTABLISHED www-data   94215       19880/apache2
```

No when I open site2.com in my browser and run **netstat -A inet -p -e** again I get the output:

```
tcp        0      0 site1.com:www     foreign-adress:37991 ESTABLISHED www-data   94215       19880/apache2   
tcp        0      0 site1.com:www     foreign-adress:37992 ESTABLISHED www-data   93034       19879/apache2
```

Now why isn't netstat showing:

```
tcp        0      0 site1.com:www     foreign-adress:37991 ESTABLISHED www-data   94215       19880/apache2   
tcp        0      0 site2.com:www     foreign-adress:37992 ESTABLISHED www-data   93034       19879/apache2
```

as I have two connections to this server through site1.com and site2.com

Is this something I misconfigured on my server?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are site1 and site2 sharing the same IP-address, are those two vhosts? That would explain it, since netstat only knows about IP-addresses.

Comment: Ah ok, yes have the same ip. Do you know why netstat is picking site1.com and not site2.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since site1 and site2 are sharing the same IP-address I can answer your last comment here. Netstat only knows about IP-addresses. If you ommit the -n parameter, netstat will do a reverese lookup in DNS or your hosts file. Snce one IP-address can only have one IN PTR record, it can only show one hostname.

You may have:

```
site1.com has 1.2.3.4
site2.com is a CNAME alias on site1.com
1.2.3.4 is site1.com
```

It's how DNS is supposed to work.

The remote webserver differentiates the requests by the Host: HTTP-header to know what content to serve.

Comment: -n showed the public ip of the server. Thanks for your answer :)